# Why would a LaserScan topic produce different results inside code?

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running a turtlebot simulation, and when I use rostopic echo /scan I get a huge array of ranges, but when my subscriber gets it, I only find 24 elements. I've verified that the subscriber is set to /scan, and it seems to reliably get the first 24 every time, but I'd estimate that there are supposed to be about 500 points. What could cause this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220630/why-would-a-laserscan-topic-produce-different-results-inside-code?/) by [Goldeelocks](https://answers.ros.org/users/25032/goldeelocks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-11-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-11-09**:
can you post the code you are using in your subscriber ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem here was that I misunderstood the data type that was being used. I was using sizeof(msg), expecting it to be an array, when it was in fact returning a vector and the correct term to use was msg.size().

---

Originally posted by [Goldeelocks](https://answers.ros.org/users/25032/goldeelocks/) with karma: 26 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0